# AD Trusts deprecated with Server 2019?

Tags: active-directory, trust-relationship

I need to setup a AD Trust relationship between two forests. I'm unable to find a Microsoft doc for this case (all I can find is a short doc for [Azure DS](https://docs.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/active-directory-domain-services/concepts-forest-trust)), is it still advised for on-premise Server 2016/2019 ?

Comment: Are you looking for this? 
https://www.vkernel.ro/blog/creating-active-directory-forest-trusts

Comment: Thanks but no; my problem is about not finding "official" Microsoft docs, so I'm worried to see this feature deprecated.

Comment: What is actually the Problem then? Are you asking if it's still supported or recommended? 
And your other question is confusing: "it still advised for on-premise Server 2016/2019 ?". 
How else would you authorize and enable the users to use resources in another forest? The only other option would be to consolidate the forests.